# Water pump pliers or pipe wrench with PVC pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pvc

Which one is the correct tool?

The task at hand is connecting PVC adaptors (male brass threads on one end, PVC/CPVC fitting to receive glue on the other) to valves with brass (?) bodies.

[image: fitting]

Comment: Edited the post with a picture.

Comment: I use curved jaw channel lock / water pump pliers on the type Luiz added.

Comment: Never heard it called "water pump pliers".  What area are you from where that is common?  Just curious.

Comment: I've heard "water pump pliers" from Pennsylvanians.

Comment: There are many names for these pliers, water pump, gas, slip-joint, dogs, Channel-Locks, and probably lots more in other parts of the country/world. Now, the hot ones are Knipex pliers made in Germany. I would use those instead of a pipe wrench. I usually only use a pipe wrench to break things loose after years of corrosion.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a [strap wrench](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-8-in-Strap-Wrench-009-193-HKY/202277618).

[image: strap wrench]

It will also come in handy if you ever need to unscrew or tighten finish pieces, like a plated pipe.

> Images and links for illustration only; not an endorsement of goods or sources.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a fitting similar to this.

[image]

I'd go with an [adjustable spanner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjustable_spanner) (also known as a crescent, or adjustable wrench). As it has smooth jaws, and will not mar the surface of the soft metal fitting.

[image]

If the fitting that this is threading into, is also a hex fitting. I'd use another adjustable spanner, to hold that in place while tightening the joint. If this is threading into a pipe, or fitting that is smooth. I'd use a pipe wrench to hold the smooth pipe/fitting in place, while tightening the joint. Wrapping a rag around the pipe before grabbing it with the pipe wrench, will reduce the marring of the pipe being held.

If you're transitioning from one type of pipe to another, you might want to consider installing a [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piping_and_plumbing_fitting#Union). This will allow you to disconnect the pipes, without having to cut the PVC/CPVC. A union that goes from brass to PVC/CPVC, might be just what you need.

[image]

If you're threading a brass fitting into a PVC/CPVC fitting, you might want to rethink that idea. If you're threading PVC/CPVC into a brass fitting, you might also want to rethink that.

---

## Update:

With the fitting posted, I'd probably; very gently, use [tongue and groove pliers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-and-groove_pliers) (also known as Channellocks).  Though  if it were me, I'd probably avoid that fitting. I'd use a PVC/CPVC to brass union instead on one side of the valve, and a hex adapter on the other.

Comment: Edited the post, the fitting doesn't have a hex part, it is round (see picture above).

Comment: still on the subject, how tight should those be? I will only know if it doesn't leak after it is done, this makes me a bit nervous. BTW: here I could only found a union like you mentioned with a cpvc body and female brass threads on one side. It think it would just add more chance for failure.